# Alamofire resume not working as expected

Tags: ios, alamofire

I´m trying to download a file, and I want to detect when it loses connectivity using `NetworkReachabilityManager` like so:

```
self.reachabilityManager?.listener = { status in
        print("Status: \(status)")
        if status == .NotReachable {
            self.download?.suspend()
        }
        else if status == .Reachable(.EthernetOrWiFi) {
            self.download?.resume()
    }
    self.reachabilityManager?.startListening()
```

Initially I start the download like this:

```
self.download = self.manager.download(.GET, url) { (temporaryURL, response) -> NSURL in
        return NSURL(string: fullFilename)!
        }
        .progress { (bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead) in
            self.setProgress(totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead: totalBytesExpectedToRead)
        }
        .response { (request, response, data, error) in
            self.handleDownloadResponse(fullFilename, response: response, data: data, error: error)
    }
```

When I switch the network off, I would think that `self.download?.suspend()` would suspend the download request, and afterwards `self.download?.resume()` would restart the download, but the progress handler is never called, and after a while the response handler fires up with a *timeout error*

Should I be doing this differently? How can I achieve this behaviour (resume the download when network is restored)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make quite a few changes to this logic for things to work as intended. Here are a set of steps to get you where you want.

1. When you lose connectivity with the request in-flight, your `response` closure will be called and the `error` will indicate a connectivity issue.
2. In the `response` closure, if the `data` parameter is not `nil`, it is the `resumeData` of the download request and can be used to resume the download from where it left off.
3. If the `data` parameter is `nil`, then you'll need to restart the download since it can't be resumed.
4. In the connectivity closure, you only need to check the `isReachable` or `isReachableOnEthernetOrWiFi` parameters.
5. Inside the reachability check, you need to make a new download request with the `resumeData` if you have it, and a completely new request if you don't.

> You cannot run the same download request again once the `response` closure has been called.

I haven't tried to use `suspend` and `resume` on download requests in the way you are. The docs do seem to imply that it's possible to use `suspend` and `resume` to do what you're doing, but the common practice is to cancel the request, then create a new one with the resume data. You'd also have to do it before the request would fail which I'm assuming is not possible.

> I would guess that your requests have already failed by the time the reachability closure is called.

Hopefully that helps get you on the right track. For more information on any of those steps, I'd refer to the [URL Loading System](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA) documentation along with the Alamofire [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: The thing is that when I turn off the connection, the response closure is not called until much later when it fires with a **timeout error**. If I turn on the connection during that lapse, the callback is finally fired with that same timeout. The way I´ve found is to cancel the download when it detects the network loss, save the `resumeData`, and try to resume it later when the connection is restored, with the saved data.

Comment: Another thing that I´ve observed is that if the user terminates the app the `response callback` won´t be fired, even if I suscribe to `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` to cancel the download to fire up that callback and save `resumeData` to disk to resume it in a future relaunch. I have observed as well there are some `CFNetworkDownload_*.tmp` files that I guess I could use to resume it as well, but I don´t know how to get that **temporary filename**, since the `destination callback` isn´t fired until the download is finished. **How should I deal with this scenario?**

Comment: `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` is not called when the user force quits your app, only when the system does. If you need to handle downloads when your app is backgrounded or terminated, you need to look into using background session configurations.

Comment: I'm using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` to save resumeData to disk, and it works after a while that the app has been backgrounded. The problem is when I kill the app... That expiration handler is not called so I subscribed to that notification and it fires up a method where the resumeData is nil (at that point) so I cancel the download but the response callback isn't fired up, so I don't get to save it...